# Different ways to extend classes through Android development?

Tags: java, android, extends

So I have been reading a tutorial on Android development, and I have come across something that I have never seen during my Java developing (mainly school work):

```java
Thread th = new Thread() { 
    public void run() {
        if (iotdHandler == null) {
            iotdHandler = new IotdHandler(); 
        }
        iotdHandler.processFeed(); resetDisplay(
        iotdHandler.getTitle(), 
        iotdHandler.getDate(),
        iotdHandler.getUrl(),
        iotdHandler.getDescription());
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
};
th.start();
```

Now the book says extend thread, and I kind of understand what its doing, in a sense, but it doesn't follow the usual way to extend a normal class in java like so:

```
public Class Dog extends Animal...
```

and then you can follow on and override methods and such. But my question is, what is it actually doing in making a reference to new Thread object, but at the same time creating a method right after it, and what I assume is overriding some sort of method in the Thread class? Since I do not know what it is called, I can't really search for it, so I apologize for the obvious question if it is one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is called anonymous class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: Look up `anonymous inner classes` in google. That's what you are seeing there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revise your Java books :) It's called an [anonymous inner class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_inner_class) and was originally introduced to facilitate Java GUI development (with AWT/Swing). Since Android UI development follows many of the same patterns, it is used quite often in Android.

What it does is instantiating a class in place (without defining it in a separate file, etc.), overriding some of its methods (int this case `run()`). You can also implement an interface this by if you provide implementations for all of its methods.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I never used it, so I had no idea how to search that method of using inner classes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, that is nothing Android specific. You can extend the same way in "normal Java". The reason for doing an class extend like that is to reduce classes, when this "class extension" is needed only once. In your example it would be the same to write

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
   @Override
   public void run() {
   [...]
   } 
};
```

and later on:

```
MyThread thread = new MyThread();
thread.start();
```

So the advantage is, that you don't need to implement a class and instantiate it later on.